# Ambiguity between 'MapGenerator.mapWidth' and 'MapGenerator.mapWidth'

Tags: c#

this is the section of code the error is in but i just cant figure out why its complaining. This came off a tutorial and i scanned the video to see what i did but i did everything the same

```
  float[,] noiseMap = Noise.GenerateNoiseMap(mapWidth, mapHeight, seed, noiseScale, octaves, persistance, lacunarity, offset);


    MapDisplay display = FindObjectOfType<MapDisplay>();
    display.DrawNoiseMap(noiseMap);
}

void OnValidate()
{
    if (mapWidth < 1)
    {
        mapWidth = 1;
    }
    if (mapHeight < 1)
    {
        mapHeight = 1;
    }
    if (lacunarity < 1)
    {
        lacunarity = 1;
    }
    if (octaves < 0)
    {
        octaves = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: you declared mapWidth twice

Comment: Is that the *only* error? It sounds like a problem in how `mapWidth` is declared, but it's hard to tell with only the snippet of code. Does the tutorial come with the code so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rename your mapWidth variable if you have prop. for it. Ex:

```
  float _mapWidth;
  public float MapWidth {
    get { return _ mapWidth; }
    set { _ mapWidth = value; }
  }
```

You can't use the same variable name in a single class.